# How to make app intent for iOS app to download pdf externally?

Tags: ios, pdf, wrapper

I have wrapper app with some buttons to generate PDFs.

I would like to download PDF files to be opened by Adobe, now when I click on the button it open it within the app which make it unable to get back and I have to force closing the app.

Comment: You should add the code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, which code?